# Getting a specific child of a node using Xpath

Tags: xml, testing, xpath, smoke-testing

I have this code here..

```
<testcase status="error" name="SMOKETEST_BP" loader-item-id="84d8c3d4-c9e1 4f8d-a690-d18c7c204555">
    <annotations>
       <annotation key="Stage" value="System Test"/>
       <annotation key="Kind" value="Smoketest"/>
       <annotation key="Situation" value="Regression"/>
       <annotation key="Domain" value="OMD"/>
       <annotation key="Business Type" value="Business Partner"/>
       <annotation key="Description" value="Create a new business partner (bp) with document"/>
    </annotations>
</testcase>
```

I want to get the value of the annotation node that has a key with a value of "Business Type".

What should my Xpath look like? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access attributes via `@attrname` syntax:

```
//annotation[@key='Business Type']/@value
```

Comment: That was fast! Thank you alecxe. :)